# Can I capture notifications that flash too fast to see?

Tags: gnome

Every once and a while, out of the corner of my eye I see the Ubuntu 20 system I'm using to run my 3D printer flash a notification at the top of the screen, but it always disappears before I can see what it says. Is there an app to record notification history I could run so I could review these things and find out what is going on? I subspect it is a momentary problem with wifi, but can't prove it.

Comment: Does it not appear when you click the clock in the middle of the top bar?

Comment: A disruption in your WiFi (including momentary) should be logged in your /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ubuntu Core 20? where GNOME is running inside a *snap*.  Ubuntu has used the *year* format for all *snap* only products since 2016, to distinguish them from the more common *year.month* or *deb* based systems designed for desktops and servers.  The 20 products are intended for *headless* operation, and whilst a snapped desktop can be added, it's not the idea product for desktop use, so I'd suggest instead using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop system instead of a server intended 20 product.